# Rerunning timed-out SLURM array jobs efficiently

Tags: slurm

I am running a large number of slurm array jobs. Some fraction of the jobs end up timing out. Is there an efficient way to identify those jobs and rerun them with an increased wall time? Currently, I am using `sacct -j jobID` to list all the jobs, manually identifying the failed jobs, and then rerunning them after updating the wall time. But this procedure is rather cumbersome. Any suggestions to improve this method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [atools](https://atools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) suite of utilities ([Github](https://github.com/gjbex/atools)) aims at solving that problem. It offers a set of commands you can use to easily track and re-submit jobs in a job array. Designed originally for PBS, but fully functioning with Slurm. See a video presentation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwTqlqQ-_7o) ([slides here](https://events.prace-ri.eu/event/1321/contributions/1497/)).